# Can I set dial-up connections as metered?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-connection, dial-up

I connect to my metered internet connection through dialup. Windows 8 (and 8.1) has special support for metered connections in order to track and reduce data usage, but the option seems to be missing for this class of connectivity.

[image: Example for Windows 8]

Or is it? Is there any way to set this kind of connections as metered?

*As reported [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c75953ab-19b7-4df2-a845-c56d544729ca/how-to-set-my-dial-up-connection-as-a-metered-connection?forum=w8itpronetworking), only Wi-Fi connection could be set as metered. But, I think, there can't be a big difference between Wi-Fi and dial-up connection in terms of metering.*

Comment: This is an issue for any kind of dial up connection. There just doesnt seem a way to do it? Does anyone know if Dial Up connections are automatically treated as metered?

Comment: @gxoptg: There can be a big difference between WiFi and dial-up as regarding the supporting driver, as most Bluetooth drivers are pretty old. There is also the possibility of an unreasonable limitation in Windows that excludes Bluetooth from metering, but in this case there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8.1 has buried this setting deep inside PC Settings.
The normal method to access it is :

1. Press the Win+I keys together and then click 'PC Settings' at the bottom.
2. Click or tap the "Network" item on the left side.
3. Click or tap your connection's name on the right side - you have to left-click again on the connection name.
4. Here you will be able to enable the option "Set as metered connection" and see other details about that connection.

If that does not work for your bluetooth dialup connection,
you might need an updated driver version from the vendor of the dial-up modem that implements the new metering support, for Windows to effectively monitor and limit bandwidth consumption.